# Basic Geometry, extract relation between sides and angles

Tags: geometry, triangles

I am asked to extract the geometric relation from this figure:

[image]

$ABC$ is not a right triangle. angle $A=\theta_1+\theta_2$. The only thing I thought about is the cosine rule:
$$BC^2=x^2+z^2-2xz\cos(\theta_1+\theta_2)$$

Can we have other relations using the height, BD, DC, or any geoemtric relation from such figure?

Update:
Can we use similar triangles between ABD and ADC

Comment: $\triangle ABD$ is not necessarily similar to $\triangle ADC$, so you can't use similarity properties. ... If you intend specifically that $\theta_1=\angle BAD$ and $\theta_2=\angle CAD$, then each of the right triangles gives you some relations; eg, $h/x$, $|BD|/x$, and $|BD|/h$ (as well as their reciprocals) are related to $\angle BAD$ by trig functions. You can also get another relation involving $\theta_1+\theta_2$ by expressing the area of $\triangle ABC$ in two ways.

Comment: Without angles: $BD^2+AD^2=AB^2$, $CD^2+AD^2=AC^2$. Involving angles: $\cos \theta_1=\frac{AD}{AB}$, $\cos\theta_2=\frac{AD}{AC}$, $\sin\theta_1=\frac{BD}{AB}$, $\sin\theta_2=\frac{CD}{AC}$.